# Add button inside an Input Tag

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have created a login `form`. I want to show a text/button that says "FORGOT?" on the right side of the password field.

For reference you guys can open this site and click on login : https://www.adda247.com/

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <button class="form-control btn btn-info " style="background:#4568B2;height:40px">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp;Continue with Facebook
    </button>
   </div>
   <br><br><br>
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <button class="form-control btn btn-default" style="height:40px;border:2px solid black">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>&nbsp;Continue with Google
    </button>
   </div>
   <br><br><br>
   <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" ></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" align="center"><b>OR</b></div>
   <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5"></div><br><br><br>
   
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" placeholder="Email">     
   </div>
   <br><br><br>
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="pass" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" placeholder="Password">
    <p class="form-control-feedback">Forgot?</p>     
   </div>
   
   <br><br><br>
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <button name="login" class="btn btn-warning form-control" style="height:40px;font-size:20px">Login</button>
   </div>
   <br><br><br>
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <p align="center" style="font-size:16px">Don't Have an Account?
     <span ><a href="#" style="color: orange">SIgn Up</a></span>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Hope you can help me !

Comment: What was the problem

Comment: "FORGOT?" is going outside the input field. It is supposed to be inside the field @Saravana

Comment: @raj you want reduce the input password width to avoid overlap on `forgot button`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correct this is the solution?
You just have to manipulate the display arguments in your css

```
           <div class="container">
           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <button class="form-control btn btn-default" style="height:40px;border:2px solid black">
                <i class="fa fa-google"></i>&nbsp;Continue with Google
                </button>
            </div>
            <br><br><br>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><b>OR</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5"></div><br><br><br>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" placeholder="Email">                   
            </div>
            <br><br><br>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="text" name="pass" class="form-control" style="height:40px; width: 90%; display: inline-block" placeholder="Password">
                <a class="form-control-feedback" style="display:inline-block; width:5%" href="#">Forgot?</a>                    
            </div>

            <br><br><br>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <button name="login" class="btn btn-warning form-control" style="height:40px;font-size:20px">Login</button>
            </div>

            <br><br><br>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <p style="font-size:16px">Don't Have an Account?
                    <span ><a href="#" style="color: orange">SIgn Up</a></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You might need to remove the container div I set it into to see,

Answer (score 0):

Add padding on password field `padding-right: 80px`

Answer (score 0):

Set the password field container to `position: relative` then set "FORGOT?" hint to `position: absolute` and `right: 1em` (so that it's fixed to its righ) then design it as you want using CSS or bootstrap classes (you'll still need a bit of pure CSS, I used the same `padding` and `height` as the input in this example).

To avoid overlapping issues, I set a  white background on the "FORGOT?" hint so any overlapping text is not shown (you could add it through the `bg-white` class as well) but you could set a `padding-right` on your `<input>` that equals the width of the "FORGOT?" hint.

```css
.form-group.has-feedback {
  position: relative;
}

.form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 1px;
    right: 1em;
    background: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-4">
    <button class="form-control btn btn-info " style="background:#4568B2;height:40px">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp;Continue with Facebook
    </button>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-4">
    <button class="form-control btn btn-default" style="height:40px;border:2px solid black">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>&nbsp;Continue with Google
    </button>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 mb-4" ></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 mb-4" align="center"><b>OR</b></div>
   <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 mb-4"></div>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-4">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" placeholder="Email">     
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback mb-4">
    <input type="text" name="pass" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" placeholder="Password">
    <p class="form-control-feedback">FORGOT?</p>     
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-4">
    <button name="login" class="btn btn-warning form-control" style="height:40px;font-size:20px">Login</button>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-4">
    <p align="center" style="font-size:16px">Don't Have an Account?
     <span ><a href="#" style="color: orange">SIgn Up</a></span>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I suggest you to not use `<br>` elements to create spaces between your items, bootstrap has classes for that (such has `.mb-4` for example).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the position relative and absolute method to move the button inside the input box.

Remove `br` and use `mt-` and `mb-` values to get spacing in bootstrap 4.

```css
.form-group.has-feedback {
    position: relative;
}
.form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 15px;
    padding: 6px 8px 9px 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-group.has-feedback .form-control {
    padding: 0 70px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-3">
            <button class="form-control btn btn-info " style="background:#4568B2;height:40px">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp;Continue with Facebook
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-3">
            <button class="form-control btn btn-default" style="height:40px;border:2px solid black">
                <i class="fa fa-google"></i>&nbsp;Continue with Google
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" align="center"><b>OR</b></div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5"></div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-3">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="pass" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" placeholder="Password">
            <p class="form-control-feedback">Forgot?</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  mb-3">
            <button name="login" class="btn btn-warning form-control" style="height:40px;font-size:20px">Login</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <p align="center" style="font-size:16px">Don't Have an Account?
                <span><a href="#" style="color: orange">SIgn Up</a></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```